# Find out what's blocking the main thread/run loop in iOS?

Tags: ios, runloop

is there a way to find out what is blocking the main thread's run loop in an iOS App, e.g. find all functions that the run loop calls that take longer than 0.1 secs to complete?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried profiling via Shark?